# I am printing the current time but I am getting a large number unrelated to time

Tags: c++, sorting, time

I need to calculate the time taken for a sort. This is a homework assignment and my teacher said that `<ctime>` includes some function from 1987 that will tell you the time from then. This is run before and after sort and the difference between the two values is the sort time. However, I can't find anything related to a time function & 1987...Does anyone know what he was talking about or is there another way to calculate sort time?

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> data;
    time_t t =time(0);

    cout<<"Vector length?: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    srand(time(0));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        data.push_back(rand()%20+1);
    }

    cout<<"Vector: "<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<data[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"Time: "<<t<<endl;
    insertionSort(data);


    cout<<"***Insertion Sorted Vector*** "<<endl;
    //cout<<"Time taken: "<<i_t2-i_t1<<endl;

    system("Pause");

    return 0;




}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time - if unsure, read the docs. Either you misremember or your teacher got the cutoff date wrong, it's Jan 1st 1970 on most systems, not something in 1987.

Comment: You know, I actually debated internally as to whether it was 1987 or 1970, but I chose the former purely because it was more recent, lol!

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/
>
> function  time
>
> ```
> time_t time (time_t* timer);
> ```
>
> Get current time Get the current calendar time as a value of type
>   time_t.
>
> The function returns this value, and if the argument is not a null
>   pointer, it also sets this value to the object pointed by timer.
>
> The value returned **generally**(**NOT always**, by user3528438) represents the number of seconds since
>   00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., the current unix timestamp).
>   Although libraries may use a different representation of time:
>   **Portable programs should not use the value returned by this function
>   directly**, but always rely on calls to other elements of the standard
>   library to translate them to portable types (such as localtime, gmtime
>   or **difftime**).

---

```
/* time example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, difftime, time, mktime */

int main ()
{
  time_t timer;
  struct tm y2k = {0};
  double seconds;

  y2k.tm_hour = 0;   y2k.tm_min = 0; y2k.tm_sec = 0;
  y2k.tm_year = 100; y2k.tm_mon = 0; y2k.tm_mday = 1;

  time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */

  seconds = difftime(timer,mktime(&y2k)); 

         //  ^^^^^^^  see difftime here

  printf ("%.f seconds since January 1, 2000 in the current timezone", seconds);

  return 0;
}
```